# copying structure into array

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am new in coding and facing problem in copying float value of structure element and passing in the `int transmit_buffer[12]`.
please help with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int i;

main(){

   int transmit_buffer[12];
   struct TX_REPORT{
       int variable1;
       float variable2;
       int variable3;
       int variable4;
       int variable5;
       int variable6;  
   };

   struct TX_REPORT transmit_report = {1, 1.5, 40, 1, 45, 7};
   memcpy(transmit_buffer, &transmit_report, sizeof transmit_buffer);
   for(i=0;i<6;i++){
       printf("%d\n",transmit_buffer[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: The code looks more or less OK - what is the actual problem that you are facing ?

Comment: You forgot to show the *expected* and the *actual* output.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not standard C, and exhibits some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There is no guarantee that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`. There is no guarantee that floating point numbers have [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representations.

<sup>However, on x86/Linux both assumptions are true.</sup>

BTW, if you want to send such a structure to a file or over the network, consider some [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques. I would recommend using textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

you must be asking about copying structure members not structure.
because what you wrote is not possible with different type variables this can be done with memcpy();

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(info.a) + sizeof(info.b) + sizeof(info.c));
// Get a pointer to the beginning of the buffer
char *p = buf;
// Copy sizeof(info.a) bytes of stuff from info.a to p
memcpy(p, info.a, sizeof(info.a));
// Advance p to point immediately after the copy of info.a
p += sizeof(info.a);
// And so on...
memcpy(p, info.b, sizeof(info.b));
p += sizeof(info.b);
memcpy(p, info.c, sizeof(info.c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks more or less OK, and you don't say what actual problem you are facing, but I'm guessing that you are not happy with the fact that the float element is displayed as an int value which does not obviously correspond with its original value. This is really just a cosmetic problem (since you're lying to printf about the type of this element), but if you want see a more meaningful version of the buffer then you could change your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   int i;
   int transmit_buffer[12];
   struct TX_REPORT{
       int variable1;
       float variable2;
       int variable3;
       int variable4;
       int variable5;
       int variable6;  
   };

   struct TX_REPORT transmit_report = {1, 1.5, 40, 1, 45, 7};
   memcpy(transmit_buffer, &transmit_report, sizeof transmit_buffer);
   for(i=0;i<6;i++){
       if (i == 1)  // handle float element as special case
           printf("%g\n",transmit_buffer[i]);
       else         // other elements are ints
           printf("%d\n",transmit_buffer[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be a union -

```
typedef struct {
       int variable1;
       float variable2;
       int variable3;
       int variable4;
       int variable5;
       int variable6;  
   } t_AsStruct;

typedef union {
    t_AsStruct as_struct;
    int as_ints[sizeof(t_AsStruct)/sizeof(int) + 1];  /* N.B. a float can be various sizes so since we can't have 0.5 ints in an array add one */
    } t_tx_report;
```

N.B. if you have control of the structure it is usually a good idea not to mix different sized types in the middle of a structure as this can result in either larger memory use due to padding or slow performance due to memory alignment problems.